# Is there a recommended way to adjust the height of the Angular Material toolbar?

Tags: angular-material2

Is there a recommended way to adjust the height of the Angular Material toolbar?

Here is an example of basic usage of the Angular Material toolbar as described here https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
   <a class="title" [routerLink]="['']">Azure B2C App1</a>
</mat-toolbar>
```

This creates a toolbar that is nearly an inch high, which is no use for anything. It's far too big.

The Material documentation page that describes customizing components states that I shouldn't use CSS to override its height, as that might break it. https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

So how am I supposed to resize it to something usable?

I notice the Angular Material documentation doesn't itself use a `mat-toolbar` for its page header, it uses a hand-rolled custom `app-nav` component instead. What should I infer from that? That after having installed one of the most heavyweight themeable component libraries around that I'm expected to handroll a themeable and responsive custom toolbar just to get a usable page header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no recommended way to adjust the toolbar size.

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4597

According to this Github issue requests for Angular Material to properly support dense toolbars on desktop in line with Material Design go back to at least 2017, but there is no sign of anything coming soon.